# XAxis entry count is greater than it should be in iOS Charts 3.0.1 in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, charts

I have two `BarChartDataSets`. One of them is always size 3 and the other is either 2 or 3. I tested out the code in version 3.0.0 and everything was working fine. When 3.0.1 came out, it broke my chart. I have the correct number of bars always, but I have six labels instead of 5 when the second dataset is only size 2. It has nothing to do with the `stringForValue` Delegate function. I set the `X` values using int's that are associated linearly with the Bar I want represented at that index, so each bar is equally spaced when working properly, but none of them are equally spaced when I have 6 labels and 5 bars.

[image]
The one on the left shows the issue and the one on the right shows what it looks like when my BarChartDataSet is size 3. It is duplicating whatever the last value on the chart is and adding it as a 6th label on the left. In 3.0.0 the one on the left would have only had 5 labels.

I dug into their code and where they create the labels in `XAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart.swift` 
right before they call 
`drawLabel()` 
I  call
`print("xAxis entries: \(xAxis.entries.count)")`
which prints 
`xAxis entries: 6`
to the console even though right before I call 
`let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet1, chartDataSet2])`
I call
`print("dataEntries1 count: \(dataEntries1.count), 
        dataEntries2 count: (dataEntries2.count)")`
which prints 
`dataEntries1 count: 3, dataEntries2 count: 2`

Comment: Can you please update your post with 3.0 and 3.0.1 screen shots and possibly code you did for same. So anyone can have idea easily and help you out asap.

Comment: I can tomorrow. I will handle it then.

Comment: @Hasya I added an image

Comment: Awesome question, with an awesome answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `xAxis.entries` and `dataSet.entries` are totally different.

`xAxis.entries` are the values that being displayed on the axis as labels, while `dataSet.entries` is the value displayed for the data, e.g. the dot value in line chart, or the bar value for bar chart.

for x axis, it calculate the label count by your data entries min/max value. In Chart 3.0, x axis behaves like y axis, so it calculates x axis entries like y axis, please take a look at `computeAxisValues()` for details.

So `xAxis.entries` and `dataSet.entries` don't have to be equal size.

If you want to set the x axis label count same as your bars count, you can call: `setLabelCount(5(6), true)`:

```
open func setLabelCount(_ count: Int, force: Bool)
{
    self.labelCount = count
    forceLabelsEnabled = force
}
```

Note, don't call the labelCount setter as it's different:

```
/// the number of label entries the axis should have
/// max = 25,
/// min = 2,
/// default = 6,
/// be aware that this number is not fixed and can only be approximated
open var labelCount: Int
{
    get
    {
        return _labelCount
    }
    set
    {
        _labelCount = newValue

        if _labelCount > 25
        {
            _labelCount = 25
        }
        if _labelCount < 2
        {
            _labelCount = 2
        }

        forceLabelsEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it out in a bit and reward you as soon as I have it working.

Comment: **horizontalBarChart.xAxis.labelCount = dataEntries1.count + dataEntries2.count** is the line that fixed it for me. Using **setLabelCount** had the issue of not placing the labels in the correct spots. You sent me in the right direction though. Thanks for saving me the time of digging into the API much. Enjoy the bounty ;)

Comment: you should be careful using labelCount setter. forcelabelEnabled means the label Count will stick to the count you set. if you use setter, the count will have chance to be different again

Comment: The labels stopped centering on their bars when I did that though. I can remember a couple other settings that I used on the y-axis that could fix that issue now that I think about it, but I did a thorough inspection after using the setter and everything seemed to be working right. I am sure I will have to change the code in the future, but choosing to use Swift as a language is asking for that right now anyhow. I don't mind the work.

Comment: It is because X axis is now like t axis, so it usually will not align. You can use index numbers like 1 2 3 to be your x Val and use formatter to display your values. Or you override computeAxisValues() to return your x vals

Comment: i use the index numbers 123, but maybe I should be starting at 0?

Comment: @Sethmr you can try

Comment: As far as I can tell, labels on the xAxis are broken as of 3.4.0. 'setLabelCount(::)' simply doesn't work properly with larger numbers of labels, regardless of whether  the 'force' flag is used. And if the 'force' flag is set to true, label positioning and justification is screwed up. At this point, after a lot of time invested in trying to get this framework to work, remaking a BarChart framework from scratch seems a better use of my time, sad to say.